# Is Halo 4 Achievement Lone Wolf Legend based on local console memory only?

Tags: achievements, halo-4

I completed Halo 4 missions 1, 3, 6, and 7 solo on Legendary.

After a week of not playing, much of my local Halo 4 memory was erased, the Infinity mode introduction played again: Armor and loadouts were reset, campaign progress was gone.

However, the last mission I had been playing (mission 8 solo on Easy) was still saved via "Resume Campaign". I finished that level, but all the levels before it are still locked. My campaign progress is still on the Halo 4 Stats website.

So, if I play through on Easy, switching to Legendary only for the missions I had not previously completed on that difficulty, so that it would show on Halo 4 Stats, that I completed every mission on Legendary, will I still unlock the "Lone Wolf Legend" achievement?

Or does it only unlock based on local memory of campaign completion?

Comment: I suspect that it is based on local memory, but this would be difficult to answer without erasing my own system's memory. You are probably in the best position to answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm the current state of things:

Last mission, on ledgenary - half way through

Rest of the missions prior to this: Locked.

---

Yes, if the game works as Halo 3 / Reach did, each mission has a marker "highest difficulty completed" - the same marker you can see online. The order you complete the missions on won't make a difference, as long as you get the local marker saying each mission was completed on legendary.

However, I'd be making sure you know why the memory was wiped before carrying on - It'd be horrific to play through again only to loose all your progress. All the markers for each mission need to be on the local system - it doesn't matter what it shows online.